# Remove taskbar from view when spawning a new process in Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, fullscreen

My full screen application covers the entire desktop (even the taskbar). However, when I start a new process from the application itself, using:

```
String command = "xterm";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

I see the new application on top of my full screen app (good) but I also see the taskbar (bad). I can provide screenshots if I'm not explaining myself correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is standard Windows behaviour (assuming that you're running the app on Windows of course). When starting a new process this gets focus by default, which means that your fullscreen app loses focus and the taskbar appears (because the new process doesn't suppress it).

I'm not sure if there's a way to bypass this behaviour though.

Good luck!